Examples of homogeneous polynomial maps between spheres
I am looking for examples of homogeneous polynomial maps between spheres in order to test some properties on them. I will summarize the ones I found and I hope you know some other.

for $z = x+iy\in \mathbb{C}$ we define $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $F(x,y) = z^k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
the Hopf maps,
for $q = x_1 + ix_2+jx_3+kx_4\in\mathbb{H}$, we consider the map $F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = q^k$,
the gradient of isoparametric functions (for example, the Cartan eiconals, the FKM polynomials),
the Veronese map,
a quadratic form defined by the Godel quaternions,
the Clifford torus,
the harmonic quadratic forms $\varphi:\mathbb{S}^3\to \mathbb{S}^n$.

However, I find it hard to seek examples in literature, especially if they are of degree greater then 2.
Thank you!
